# Is it possible to "free" top-level universally quantified variables using tactics in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

In short, I would like to go from this:

```
 proof (prove)
 goal (1 subgoal):
  1. ⋀ myVar . somePredicate myVar
```

to this:

```
 proof (prove)
 goal (1 subgoal):
  1. somePredicate myVar
```

by using tactics. The only solution I can find is to write a new `lemma` for example:

```
 lemma myPredicateHolds_aux : "somePredicate myVar"
   sorry
```

and then the original `⋀ myVar . somePredicate myVar` usually can be solved by writing:

```
 using myPredicateHolds_aux by blast
```

but I wonder whether there is a better way (using tactics), for convenience, and because, if the property is very intricate, `blast` may fail.

Comment: something like `(appliy meta_allI)`? Vague recollection.

Comment: The only definition of `meta_allI` I could find was:
```lemma meta_allI: "∀ x. P x ⟹ (⋀x. P x)"```

And then applying it gives me:
```⋀myVar. ∀myOtherVar. somePredicate myOtherVar```
so almost, but `myOtherVar` is still still quantified using this other kind of forall `∀`, so it is not a free variable either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `proof (prove)` suggests you're writing a proof script, in which case you can use `subgoal for myVar`. The "isar-ref" manual says a little more about it, I think (though it may be a bit dense).

You can also, and I believe this is usually the "preferred" way to do it, go into structured Isar proof mode and use `fix`:

```
proof -
  fix myVar
  show "somePredicate myVar"
  proof ...
```

Comment: Thank you, `subgoal for myVar` is exactly what I was looking for.